# Find all positive integers n with the property that for each positive divisor d of n, we have that d + 1 is a divisor of n + 1.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would I approach or solve a problem such as this?
I know that $n = d*a$ and $n+1 = (d+1)*b$ for some integer $a$, $b$. So I substituted them into each and got
$$d(a-b)=b-1$$
But how would I go from here?

Comment: Every prime odd number is such.

Comment: and $1$. But is that all of them? $n$ must be odd, for starters.

Answer (score 2):

Only 1 and odd primes satisfy this condition.

Suppose $n$ is not $1$ and not prime. Then $n=ab$ where $2\le a\le b$. Then $b+1$ divides $ab+1$. So it divides $(a-1)b$. Since it is coprime with $b$ it must divide $a-1$ . This contradicts $a\le b$.

Comment: What do you mean by "So it divides (a−1)b. Since it is coprime with b it must divide a−1"

Comment: $$(a=1)b=(ab+1)-(b+1).$$

Comment: I still don't quite understand, what divides $(a-1)b and why is it coprime with b?

Comment: $b+1$  divides both $ab+1$ and $b+1$ so $b+1$   divides the difference which is $(a-1)b$. Number  $b$  is co-prime with number $b+1$.Ok?